# Files can't be found after building with electron-packager

Tags: webpack, electron, webpack-file-loader

I am trying to use webpack to transpile (and bundle) ES6 code I've written for electron's main (not renderer). When I transpile and run, the application works OK. But after bundling with `electron-packager` icon image (that i used for tray) can't be loaded.

Here is the error I get when I try to run exe (I am on Windows 10) built by `electron-packager`:

[image: the error window]

Here is the ES6 code for electron's main process:

```
import electron, { app, BrowserWindow, Tray} from 'electron';

let appIcon = null;
let appIconPath = null;

if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
    appIconPath = require('./resources/images/icon-black-16.png');
} else {
    appIconPath = require('./resources/images/icon-16.png');
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    // hide dock icon if possible
    if (app.hasOwnProperty('dock')) {
        app.dock.hide();
    }

    // tray icon
    appIcon = new Tray(appIconPath);

    app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
        // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
        // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
        if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
            app.quit();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path');

const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');
const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/');

var config = {
    target: "electron",
    entry: SRC_DIR + '/main.js',
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=files/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: Have the same issue.

Comment: Still no work around? I have the same issue.